# Setting transition-duration for custom-segue class

Tags: xcode, animation, swift, segue, transition

I have a custom-segue class for a modal segue, and I need to change the duration of the transition, but I can't figure out how, or if it's even possible inside the class.

Any suggestions on how to do this the correct way would be appreciated.